# Error: timeout when connecting to MongoDb Atlas using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to connect my mongoose with my MongoDB Atlas Cluster,it shows that i have a connection with the database but i can't save , and that erreur :const err = new MongooseError(message);
^

MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

i already try to change my DNS and selecting the version to "2.2.12" by the drop-down menu

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const app = express();
require("dotenv").config({ path: '.env' });

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Server is up and running"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`));


mongoose.connect(
process.env.MONGO_PROD_URI, {
 useNewUrlParser: true,
 useUnifiedTopology: true,
 useCreateIndex: true,
}
,() => console.log("Database connected!"));

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: String,
 age: Number,
 isAdult: Boolean,
 joined: {
   type: Date,
   default: Date.now,
 },
});

const User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);

const newUser =  new User({
 name: "Elliot Alderson",
 age: 23,
 isAdult: true,
});

newUser.save().then(() => console.log("Saved new user"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Can you just try this.**

Try this method to add new User and test it with Postman :

```
router.post("/addUser", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var newUser = new User({
      name: "Elliot Alderson",
      age: 23,
      isAdult: true,
    });
    const newUser = await User.save();
    res.send(newUser);
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

Otherwise Log in to your mongo account and add your IP address from the
Network Access part. or allow access from anywhere to your database.

[image]

Comment: tnx, but it didn't work, I just confirm that the server won't start listening until it's connected to the database.